# Cannot select child p tag CSS

Tags: html, css

I am using Bootstrap 3 for my new website and for the life of me I cannot select the p tag in the example below. I have tried everything I can think of and I have been stuck on this problem for the last 3 hours (sad I know).

I have tried the following below to name a few examples

```
 .p 
 body > section > .container > .row > .col-sm-5 > p
```

and then (for each one I tried).

```
 { 
 color: red;
 }
```

As well I have tried to give the tag a class name and then call that class or ID directly... still nothing. I have tried every combo I can think of.

Can anyone tell me how to select the p element so I can change the text colour? The following is taken using firebug in firefox, again I am looking for the p tag.

[image]

**EDIT**

html code as requested

```
<section id="slider" class="bg-color np">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row item">
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <p id="test">Our product is one of a kind!</p> <!-- this is p tag -->
                <form  id="newsletter" action="" class="form-inline" role="form">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter your email">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>  
                  </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <img src="img/cover.png" class="img-responsive main" alt="product" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You said you've tried calling a class or ID directly, that would work unless another style for that element has more weight. Did you try using !important?

Comment: @radha Thanks for the reply. Sorry I am not quite sure what you are referring too?

Comment: @Leifingson Thanks for the quick reply. No I have not, I just started learning CSS. Ive never even heard of that property. I will try it now

Comment: try to make a fiddle or give the site url

Comment: @Leifingson I added an ID as <p id="test"> and then in the CSS I went #test !important and called color: red but still no luck. Is that the correct usage

Comment: @radha the site is still under dev so I cannot provide a url link :(

Comment: post your html and css man..?? This is not the way to ask a question..!!

Comment: _try something like_ ___color:red !important;___ [___put ur code on here___](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @SajadLfc sorry my apologies I thought the screen shot would do to make things cleaner

Comment: Post html code to inspect exacltly

Comment: @Teddy13 : U must post the Html..!! its very important to answer your question..!! So please..!!

Comment: @SajadLfc Thank you for letting me know. I have posted, if you need the entire thing (which is quite huge), let me know.

Comment: Its working see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sCyYn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Try this,***

```
body > section > .container > .row > .col-sm-5 > p
{ 
    color: red !important;
}
```

[***FIDDLE***](http://jsfiddle.net/sCyYn/1/)

[***for more about !important visit http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules***](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules)

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! I needed that !important property

Answer (score 1):

Check this..!!

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JN2rD/1/)

CSS:

```
#test{

    color:red !important;

}
```

you must be applying the css in two different ways..!! so u must tell which one should take. so '**!important**'.

Comment: I can see it is working there but it is not working in my project:(. I tried that initially when I first started

Comment: then give a class name to the p tag..!! and apply the css for the class..!!

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated but Pranav Ram gave me what I was missing. +1 for your help

Comment: yah..!! he is right..!! but it is because..!! you are applying the css in two different ways..!! so u must tell which one should take..!! thats why '!important'